# In bash how do I search for a variable then display the line above it

Tags: bash, search, sed

I have a file like this:

```
multipath {  
wwid 3600507630bffc5e10000000000001048  
alias mpath3  
path_grouping_policy failover  
}
```

I want to search for mpath3 then output the wwid line above it.  I need this to only output the wwid for the mpath I search for.  Currently it is returning values for mpath3 and mpath 34 and 35.

```
i=mpath3

sed ":a;s/\n/&/2;tb;$!{N;ba};:b;/$i/!D;" /etc/multipath.conf)
```

output:

```
multipath { wwid 3600507630bffc5e10000000000001118 alias mpath3 multipath { wwid 3600507630bffc5e10000000000001047 alias mpath34 multipath { wwid 3600507630bffc5e10000000000001048 alias mpath35 } }
```

Answer (score 3):

This should be solvable simply with grep (the `-B` flag allows you to extract lines of context before the match):

```
grep -B1 "mpath3$" /etc/multipath.conf
```

note you need the `$` to exclude the `mpath34` and other results.

Comment: Wow I was making this way harder than it needed to be.  Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the boundary marker `\b`:

```
sed ':a;s/\n/&/2;tb;$!{N;ba};:b;/\b'"$i"'\b/!D;' /etc/multipath.conf
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '/mpath3/{print wwid} {wwid=$2}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Using awk:

```
awk -v s="mpath3" '$1=="wwid"{wwid=$2;next} $2==s{print wwid}' /etc/multipath.conf
3600507630bffc5e10000000000001048
```